# How to change header and footer color by selecting color picker and radio button?

Tags: javascript, html

i'm in big urge. The task may be simple, but not for me :)

I have a task to make color selection with color picker, then choose radio buttons of header or footer and submit button. I have already searched whole internet and have no answer how to write correct JS to make it work... HELP!

HTML -

```html
<div class="colors" id="co">
    <label for="spp">Choose color:</label>
    <input type="color"/><br>
    <input name="CC"  type="radio" id="header" value="0"/>Header<br>
    <input name="CC" type="radio" id="footer" value="1"/>Footer<br>
    <button onclick="return changeColor();">Change</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript -

```js
function changeColor() {
    var radio = document.documentElement["sp"];
    for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++) {
        if (radio[i].checked == true) {

            var newColor = radio[i].value;
            document.getElementById("changeColor").style.backgroundColor = newColor;
        return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: What are u even doing? What does this line of code refer to - `var radio = document.documentElement["sp"];` ?

Comment: Well, I freshly started to learn, and yet haven't figured out how to write it correctly (facepalm)

Comment: But does it even refer to any element or is it a mistake or typo?

Comment: sp were ID of other div, ive got it all wrong. :)

Comment: So u mean, U had to write spp but u wrote sp(typo)